# Logging messages in Hive .hql file

Tags: hive, hiveql, beeline

I have some insert statements to run in Hive. I am planning to put them in .hql file and run it through beeline -f option. Is there a way I can echo some log messages in between inserts so that I know the progress. Like :

echo "Starting the inserts ........."
   insert1

echo "Insert 1 complete"

insert2

echo "Insert script is complete"

I tried putting echo statements by using linux shell command echo as 
!echo ""

But it's not recognizing echo as a command

Answer (score 0, accepted):

!sh echo ...

---

```
!sh echo "Starting the inserts ........."      

insert ...

!sh echo "Insert 1 complete"

insert ...

!sh echo "Insert script is complete"
```

Answer (score 1):

```
set msg = "Starting Insert";
set msg;

insert into .... ;

set msg = "Insert complete";
set msg;
```

Comment: This way worked for me, while the accepted answer didn't. Thanks!